# What material is Doomsday's containment suit made of?

Tags: dc, doomsday

[Doomsday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_(DC_Comics)) made his first appearance in ***[Superman: The Man of Steel # 18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_The_Man_of_Steel)***. In his first appearance itself, he was shown with his containment suit.

[image]
 <sub>***Superman: The Man of Steel #18 cover***</sub>

Since then, the **Containment Doomsday** has made his appearance in several Superman and Justice League comics and also in the Injustice: Gods Among us game and most recently in the 2018's [The Death of Superman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Superman_(film)) movie.

In all the things I've encountered, I couldn't find details about the containment suit.

Is there any mention (in the comics, movies or otherwise *etc*.) about the material composition of Doomsday's containment suit? Like what is it made of, its durability *etc.*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If Doomsday was so powerful, why couldn't he get out of his restraints?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20594/if-doomsday-was-so-powerful-why-couldnt-he-get-out-of-his-restraints)

Comment: The indicated possible duplicate mentions the "immensely strong Calatonian alloy cables," presumably referring to the metal cables seen on the cover. By the containment suit, presumably the OP is referring to the green suit he's contained in (in addition to/instead of just the cables).

Answer (score 1):

According to the monster's origin story in *[Superman/Doomsday:  Hunter/Prey](https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Superman-Doomsday-Hunter-Prey/Issue-2)*, issue 2, the suit was not designed to *contain* Doomsday.  It was actually just a burial garment in which he was clothed after being "killed" by the Calatonians' energy being, [the Radiant](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Radiant_(New_Earth)).  The Calatonians were apparently unaware that Doomsday would resurrect itself, and the robes and chains in which its corpse was wrapped were merely symbolic.

[image: Doomsday burial]

> Doomsday was suited and chained so his spirit would not escape in the afterlife.

Presumably, for religious reasons, the garments and bindings were made of sturdy material, but they were probably the same as would have been used to bind the body of any other Calatonian killer.